# Integration with stripe, have a single source of truth or have info of the user status in our DB

Tags: design, design-patterns, data

So We're integrating our application with stripe and we have different products

There are 2 options :

- Have stripe as a single source of truth, anytime we need to check the permissions of a user we call a stripe api, get the product and decide accordingly.

  - advantage : single source of truth
  - inconvenience: manipulate subscriptions outside stripe (set a premium person without paying ...) / too many calls to stripe ....
- Integrate the stripe webhooks and put everything in the database

  - advantage : flexibility with the data
  - inconvenience: keep track and maintain another layer just for the redundancy data (especially on cancelation, error in renewal....)

Is there any best practice, or an experience on this which is better on the long term ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long term you want to own your data so the second option is best. Short term if you don't have the people with the knowledge to manage that data you can be better off using the first and working to transition to the second after more growth and resources are available to take ownership of your data. This is similar calculus to cloud platforms. There are options for lower barrier to entry, but they often are expensive long term as you lose needed power and flexibility. Many times rolling out new features or products quickly and cheaply is more useful to determine their worth than taking time to build the most robust solution from the start.

In the current age this extends to data ownership as machine learning has become better and more used than ever. Using services where you don't have full control of your data means someone else is using and profiting off your data in most cases. Mining data for previously unknown insights is the secret to massive growth in our current age, giving away that data needs to be a conscious and calculated choice.